# c++ sizeof giving an error unhandled exception at

Tags: c++, crash, runtime-error, sizeof

This is just a basic print a sentence array string.  I am new to c++ only used JAVA and similar languages never c before.  Trying to learn it by going through every different sort algorithm and data structure.

But before I could get started just testing my string array would give me an error.  I have no idea why it is giving me a error.  Compiles fine in fact runs and prints the intend content but crashes with a error if you are debugging it.  Can anyone explain to me as to why that is.  Tried `size()` and `length()` from c++ library but had to use sizeof()
'

```
//BubbleSort.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string something[14];
    something[0] = "Kate";
    something[1] = "likes";
    something[2] = "lots";
    something[3] = "of";
    something[4] = "cake";
    something[5] = "in";
    something[6] = "her";
    something[7] = "mouth";
    something[8] = "and";
    something[9] = "will";
    something[10] = "pay";
    something[11] = "a";
    something[12] = "lot";
    something[13] = "lol";
    int some = sizeof(something);
    some--;
    for (int i = 0; i < some; i++)
    {
        cout << something[i] << " " ;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should consider using `std::vector` or `std::deque`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sizeof(something)` would not return 14 as you expect , but it returns `sizeof(string)*14` so you are encountering a buffer overflow when you try to print . 
What you need is

```
some = sizeof(something)/sizeof(string)
```

or as mentioned by  @Tiago you could use

`some = sizeof(something)/sizeof(something[0])`

Also as @James suggested you should look into `std:vector` .

Comment: you also can do this: sizeof(something)/sizeof(* something)

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj IF that `something` was an array

Comment: Just for completeness... `sizeof x` returns the number of bytes occupied by the variable `x`, and `std::string` objects are sure to occupy much more than 1 byte - that's why your loop iterates too many times and `cout << something[i]` ends up trying to read memory off the end of the `something` array. The point is there's no really convenient way to get the number of elements in an inbuilt C++ array (just the total / element thing with sizeof given)- they're not objects and `.length()` won't work - that's why `std::vector` is good to use - it is an object and provides these kind of value adds.